# Embeded Matplotlib Graph into Tkinter crashes on Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

While porting Python 2.7 script to Python 3.5, this code crashes in Windows Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit):

```
import tkinter as Tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

root = Tk.Tk()

fig = plt.figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.02, rely=0.14, relheight=0.83, relwidth=0.96)

Tk.mainloop()
```

The root cause is `get_tk_widget().place()` method. Windows Event View provides this info:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.5.1150.1013, time stamp: 0x5665f370
Faulting module name: tcl86t.dll, version: 8.6.2.4, time stamp: 0x55dbf93d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000165a9
Faulting process id: 0x26a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1364cdb6d7ba9
Faulting application path: C:\Anaconda3\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Anaconda3\DLLs\tcl86t.dll
```

Is it a well-known bug? How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure out just by reinstalling matplotlib via pip:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```