# Tkinter Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) with anaconda python 3.5

Tags: tkinter, overflow, python-3.5

I'm having problems with Tkinter. A program is working very well with python 3.4 but with python 3.5 I'm getting exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

I know that I should just post a link to a program but given the circumstances I indulge myself in doing that here. I've narrowed it down to a simple file.
https://github.com/dickreuter/Poker/blob/master/GUI_Tkinter.py

As you can see, I'm using a separate thread to update the GUI. But this shouldn't be an issue. It all works under python 3.4 but not under python 3.5. Any suggestions what has been changed in tkinter in those versions would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps something is wrong with your python 3.5 installation. That code seems to work (linux / windows 10, 64 bit python 3.5 (python.org), program started from command prompt). You could test for instance if `import numpy` works.

Comment: My friend has exactly the same problem. Everything else seems to work fine with my python 3.5. I'm using the latest anaconda distribution.

Comment: This might help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/34273383/5781248

Comment: please don't link to an external file. Read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the anaconda distribution. pip uninstall matplotlib and pip install matplotlib resolved the issue.